# A problem related to Schwarz reflection principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose there is a function $f$ which is analytic in $\Omega$ except a simple pole at $a\in\Omega$, such that $(z-a)f(z)$ is continuous on $\bar{\Omega}$ with $f(z)=\bar{z}$ on $\partial\Omega$. Prove that the function $g(z)=(z-a)f(z)-(z-a)\bar{a}$ is constant. What is $\Omega$?

It should be consistent with the problem if we assume $\Omega$ to be the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$, then we may use the reflection principle with respect to $\mathbb{D}$ to extend $g$ to an entire function and then conclude using the Liouville theorem that $g$ is a constant. But how can we see that this is the most general case that can happen?

Comment: Very intriguing question. By $\Omega$ I assume you mean a simply connected domain? If we are concerning ourselves with an arbitrary simply connected domain then $\partial \Omega$ could yield many problems, like for example not having finite length and thus integration techniques might be tricky. 

Typically, the Shwarz reflection principle requires "nice" boundaries and properties in order to reflect properly. I am unaware of a general boundary reflection principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$. Its boundary values are real and positive:

$$f(z)(z-a) - \overline{a}(z-a) = \overline{z}(z-a) - \overline{a}(z-a) = \overline{z-a}(z-a) =\lvert z-a\rvert^2.$$

If $g$ weren't constant, $g(\Omega)$ would be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, hence $v := \operatorname{Im} g$ would attain nonzero values in $\Omega$. Since $v$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline{\Omega}$, it would attain a strictly positive maximum or a strictly negative minimum, necessarily at a point $z_0 \in \Omega$. But $v$ is a real-valued harmonic function, by assumption non-constant, hence $v$ has no local maxima or minima, contradicting the assumption.

Thus $g$ is constant, $g(z) \equiv r^2$. Thus $\Omega$ is a bounded domain whose boundary is contained in $C_r(a) = \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z-a\rvert = r\}$, and that means $\Omega = D_r(a) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert < r\}$.

Comment: Can say that $v=\Im(g)$ is harmonic and $v=\Im(g)=0$ on the boundary. Then by maximum principle, $v$ takes the max. and min. on the boundary. Hence $v=\Im(g)=0$ on $\Omega$. And by CR equation $u=\Re(g)=constant$?

Comment: @mnmn1993 Yes, no problem with that.